# Change the ID of a standard TYPO3 mailform

Tags: forms, typo3

Every Form object created in TYPO3 has the ID "mailform".

```
<form action="thanks/" id="mailform" name="mailform" enctype="multipart/form-data[...]
```

This seems to be a problem since I have 2 forms on 1 page, and when (I think) the IDs are the same, the validation script doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As reported here: http://lists.typo3.org/pipermail/typo3-english/2006-April/024467.html

in your main template setup field add this code:

> tt_content.mailform.20.formName >

now every mailform will have a different unique (a hash) form id

Answer (score 0):

Use the `form` extension (system extension since TYPO3 4.6, see the [release notes](http://wiki.typo3.org/TYPO3_4.6.0#Form)).

You can define an individual `id` in the tab `Form`.

Answer (score -1):

1) Look into the Extension files.. maybe you can change it somewhere there easyily.
2) Is it possible for you to change the id maybe via javascript/jquery?
maybe it helps you fix the problem with the validation script:

```
$('#mailform').each(function(index,value){
  index++;
  $(this).attr('id', 'mailform'+index);
});
```

Comment: Interesting! I'll try this. Thanks!

Comment: your "answer" can be put under 30% of all questions. it's not a good answer.

Comment: @cweiske instead of telling us if something is or is not a good answer you can start giving it a reason. seems like your comment is like 30% of all other comments. its not a good comment. (reason: read first sentence).